# FQL query php:how to make a query to find the number of likes got to the users comments

Tags: php, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

how to  make a query to find  the  number  of likes got to  the users comments

Comment: Could you elaborate- the # of likes someone got on their specific comment?

Comment: @anna     eg. select likes from comment where fromid=me();
how can i get  the oupt

Answer (score 0):

It has to be based on an object, such as a feed post, event, etc. Once you know what kind of object you want to get comments on, you can do:

```
fql?q=select user_likes from comment where fromid=me() and object_id in (....)
```

You can't query with out a subquery in the where() that joins on an indexable column, such as, object_id. It's how Facebook forces you to join to their index tables, to narrow results (and prevent you from doing full scan queries like "select *").

The problem is, you have to pick a kind of object to look at.  For example, if you want comments on the posts the user made:

```
fql?q=select user_likes from comment where post_id in (select post_id from stream where filter_key in (select filter_key from stream_filter where uid = me()))
```

You can play around with various conditions on the indexible columns (marked by *). Test it in:

[graph api explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

[facebook fql comment table documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)